# Slash in json encoded variable breaks slim api route

Tags: php, json, routes, slim

i created a route in slim api like this:

```
$app->put('/user/:one', function ($one) {
```

i know i created the put wrong by using it as a get, but i can't change the app since it's live. 
So I have to find a way to change this so it works when the json encoded variable contains a slash. 
When one of the fields in the json variable contain a slash the route thinks another variable is being declared.
In this url the password contains a slash and thus breaks my route:

```
http://someapi.nl/someappApi/api.php/user/%7B%22uuid%22:%2267b80bda2ab6f83d%22,%22username%22:%22bladude%22,%22screen_state%22:%22Aan%20het%20werk%22,%22name%22:%22bladude%22,%22last_name%22:%22asdf%22,%22email%22:%22someexample@live.nl%22,%22password%22:%22bie/rtje/%22%7D
```

is there a way to tell slim api it should see the entire url as one variable??? or escape the slash?

Comment: your app will need to fix that on the UI side. Slim is doing exactly what it is suppose to do.

Comment: I will in an update but for now a ugly hack will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wildcard route to capture the entire query string...

$app->put('/user/:one+', function ($one) {

Comment: Yess, I had all ready solved but this was the way, it made the first var an array if there were multiple slash so I put a check on that and if it did I looped through values and pasted it together to a string :), thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SLIM 3

```
$app->get('/hello[/{params:.*}]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
$params = explode('/', $request->getAttribute('params'));

// $params is an array of all the optional segments
```

});

I found this solution at "[Slim 3 - Slash as a part of route parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203681/slim-3-slash-as-a-part-of-route-parameter)"