# Slim 3 - Slash as a part of route parameter

Tags: php, regex, slim, slim-3

I need to compose URLs with parameters that can contain a slash /. For example, the classic `/hello/{username}` route. By default, `/hello/Fabien` will match this route but not `/hello/Fabien/Kris`. I would to ask you how can I do it in Slim 3 framework.

Comment: By adding another placeholder `/hello/{username}/{name}`?

Comment: @revo it is not possible, because there can be 2 or more slashes and I need to store everything after /hello/ to one variable, in this case, parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Route placeholders](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-placeholders):

> For “Unlimited” optional parameters, you can do this:

```
$app->get('/hello[/{params:.*}]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $params = explode('/', $request->getAttribute('params'));

    // $params is an array of all the optional segments
});
```

Comment: Thx, that is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can just as well use `$args`:

```
$app->get('/hello[/{route:.*}]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $route = $args['route']; // Whole Route
    $params = explode('/', $route); // Route split
});
```